# Loop through a list of Tags and compare xWiki

Tags: velocity, xwiki

I have a xwiki project with a Tag system implemented. What I am trying to do is solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394365/how-do-i-check-for-documents-with-more-than-1-tag-in-xwiki) problem. When I click on a Tag I get the correct output but I want to sort the documents according to their other Tags, which means I need a way to search by multiple tags. What I have done is get a list of documents tagged with the first tag then use `#foreach` to look through each document for the Tags I need to show.

```
#set ($tag = "$!{request.get('tag')}")
#set ($list = $xwiki.tag.getDocumentsWithTag($tag))
#foreach($doc in $list)
    #set ($tags = $xwiki.tag.getTagsFromDocuments($doc))
    #foreach($tg in $tags) 
        #if($tg == 'Tutorial')
        {{html}} #displayDocumentList($doc false $blacklistedSpaces){{/html}}
         #end
    #end
 #end
```

The above code looks for documents that are tagged with `$tag` and `Tutorial`. Does not look very efficient but I am not looking for efficiency at this point of time, I just need it to work and the above code does not and I have no idea why.

EDIT::::

I tried a different solution. This time I get a `$list` and `$list2` where `$list` are all the documents with the first tag and `$list2` are the docs with the second tag. Then I compare each document's full name from one list to every document's full name in the second list. Still does not work. Here's the code,

```
#set ($tag = "$!{request.get('tag')}")
#set ($list = $xwiki.tag.getDocumentsWithTag($tag))
#set ($list2 = $xwiki.tag.getDocumentsWithTag('Tutorial'))
  #foreach($doc in $list)
     #foreach($doc2 in $list2)
        #if($doc.fullName == $doc2.fullname)
              $doc
        #end
    #end
  #end
```

EDIT 2::::

So now the `#foreach` loop gives me the correct output but my problem is I want to show the $doc as it would be shown if `#{{html}} #displayDocumentList($doc false $blacklistedSpaces){{/html}}` was valid. Is not because I think the first params is supposed to be a list and here $doc is just one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Here is how to display your document. Once you get `$doc` use this line to show your document,  `{{display reference="$doc"/}}`

Here is the link to the [Display Macro](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Display+Macro)